# Android - Shake emulator on linux

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I've been trying to open developer tools from react-native on android emulator, using Linux (ubuntu 16.04).

I've tried to ctrl+m with no luck.

Also, when i try to

> adb shell input keyevent 82

It says, device is offline.

How to shake the device?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ADB to shake the Android emulator for 1 second with the following command:

```
adb emu sensor set acceleration 100:100:100; sleep 1; adb emu sensor set acceleration 0:0:0
```

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: This command works for me.